# Do you get a penalty to Intimidation checks if you're a smaller size?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, creature-size, social-stats

By the rules, would a gnome get a penalty on intimidating a human because they are small?

Comment: Is this asking whether the rules state you should get a penalty, or asking what other DMs would rule?

Comment: whether the rules state you should. Although I'm open to hearing peoples opinions.

Comment: Beware that we don’t do “I want to hear opinions” questions here, so you won’t get any of that. We’re rather unlike the discussion forums that people are more familiar with. Check out the [tour] for more about our design.

Comment: Ever find yourself with a bee in the car?

Answer (score 12):

No, you don't. The section on Intimidation in the PHB says nothing about there being bonuses or penalties based on relative size. It's entirely dependent on your Charisma score, Proficiency bonus and whatever additional features you've picked up to boost your intimidation skills.

Of course, the DM still has the freedom to apply Disadvantage when it makes sense, but size alone probably shouldn't be the deciding factor there. It might make sense for a Gnome to have Disadvantage when trying to intimidate an Orc into laying down his arms in a face-to-face confrontation when both sides have weapons drawn and ready, but there's no reason to believe a Gnome is less intimidating than a Human when the same Orc is a tied up prisoner and someone is threatening to cut their tongue out.

Comment: Don't underestimate the gnome, it could be your last mistake.

Comment: @NautArch I know that. The average Orc probably doesn't :)

Comment: My group's halfling rogue used to say that being short just means you can groinpunch people easier.